# Jest Ionic test fails - unexpected token import

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, ionic3, jestjs

I am not sure why importing GA into my unit test fails. How can I fix this?

Maybe the JEST error should point me into the right direction, but unfortunately it does not:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
```

....

```
/Users/me/app/node_modules/@ionic-native/google-analytics/index.js:20
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      2 | import { Http } from '@angular/http';
      3 | import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
    > 4 | import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';
```

By instruction I extended my `package.json` with

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/node_modules"
],
```

but it still fails with the same error

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2081#issuecomment-300552596 this might help in your case

Comment: Having the same issue - did you ultimately solve this somehow? Above link did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: No, neither for me. Do you have a solution?

Comment: any solution to this found yet?

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found a solution to this problem,

1. Do not run `npm run eject` in your code base,
2. You can pass the flag in your `package.json` test command as given below,
   `--env=jsdom --transformIgnorePatterns 'node_modules/(?!(@ionic|<other-package-need-to-transform>)/)`

this solution is common for ionic/react and ionic/angular